# XSSF worksheet cells having random styles

Tags: excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel, xssf

Is there any way to set style for all next cells in excel worksheet? Like for the rest of the document after certain cell?
I am using Apache POI 3.9 for exporting data to excel worksheet. Client wants colored font for invalid data. Everything is running fine, but sometimes, when I put text in empty cells in "INFORMATION" column, it makes font colored red, even after reseting cell style or explicitly asking for condition and then setting default cell style. Youre more likely to get my idea from pic of code. [image: Data export to excel using apache poi]

Ive uploaded some pic of excel too. Hope it helps. It starts on row 37, text somehow changes color even after not running through setting conditions. I havent recognized any pattern in there. [image: invalid data showcase]

I tried to change conditions, change cell style setting location in code... Had no effect.

**Edit:** It seems like the problem is not in AP but in Excel itself. It looks like the font color is changed after user input and its caused by autoformatting that is based on the context. So only option here is to change style of previous data. Could not find any other solution to this.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.9 was released in 2012](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9), maybe try a version that's at least from this decade?

Comment: Unfortunately this decision is not upon me.

Comment: If you want to use a 10 year old version with known security issues, that's your choice, but you can hardly expect people to help you with backporting 10 years of fixes for free...